# Help me finding a hoster that allows MySQL Replication please

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

Now as I found out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605435/the-right-way-automated-synchronization-between-2-mysql-db/7605479#7605479) that I should use Replication for my project, I need a Hoster that allows me to do so. Unfortunately my current hoster doesn't unless I buy a real expensive package. Currently I'm paying around 50$ a month and I wouldn't like paying much more as I don't need many exclusive features apart from replication (got maybe 5000 visitors on a good day).

- I don't want to spend much money, as I don't have much traffic (maybe a few thousand unique visitors on a good day)
- I actually need only a fast MySQL DB to set up for replication
- Preferably in germany as my visitors come from germany too

I just can't find any information about that on hosters webpages, and I thought it might be faster to ask others before writing asking every hoster personally.

Anyone can help me here ? What hoster are you using for MySQL DB replication?

Comment: If you have pricing complaints, it's generally a good idea to include what sort of budget **is** acceptable to you. (Sometimes it turns out the asker needs to be informed they're being a cheapskate.) Replication isn't exactly a beginner feature to start with.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Edited my question to include that. Maybe I'm a cheapskate, but apart from that really important feature I don't need anything extraordinary. Hope I can find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Amazon RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/) supports the MySQL engine and [offers replication](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/#86). You can launch an Amazon RDS instance and use it from your existing hosting provider without moving your application.

Comment: Not sure whether that really suits me, because I don't exactly know how much traffic my DB creates and I'm hoping it also works with a local DB, but I'll give it a shot - can't find anything better anyway. So thanks for the suggestion!